# How to identiy new/repeat customers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of ~55k customer sales. I need to create a column to identify if a sale was repeat or new business based on customer name. I have columns A/B and I want to create column C as shown below:

[image: Excel Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)>1,"Repeat","New")
```

Comment: just an FYI, the `>1` is not really needed as anything greater than 0 will read as true.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I know but only if its 2 or higher a value is repeated

Comment: I would have used: `B$1:B1` and then it would be `0` But to each their own

Comment: Correct! @ScottCraner

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that Column A is sorted ascending:

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$B$1:B1,)),"Repeat", "New")
```

If the data is not sorted we need to switch to COUNTIFS(), which is not as optimized as MATCH and will cause issues in the calc if the data set it too large(>10,000)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,"<"&A2,$B:$B,B2),Repeat", "New")
```

Again put that in C2 and copy down the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

### `MINIFS` Beats `COUNTIFS`?

If there is only one first date associated with each customer then the data has not to be sorted and you can use the following:

```
=IF(A2>MINIFS($A:$A,$B:$B,B2),"Repeat","New")
```